# Ember.js length of array of related objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im using Ember Data and Ember CLI. I have a simple one-to-many relationship between two models. I'm trying to create a computed property that returns the number of items that are attached to the current model.

**models/account.js**

```
// Account model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:   DS.attr('string'),
  notes:  DS.hasMany('note', { async: true })
});
```

**models/note.js**

```
// Note model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  body:     DS.attr('string'),
  date:     DS.attr('number'), // unix timestamp
  account:  DS.belongsTo('account', { async: true })
});
```

**controllers/account/index.js**

```
// account/index controller
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  oldNotesCount: function() {
    var notes = this.get('notes');
    console.log('=-=', notes.length); // undefined *****
    return notes.length;
  }.property('notes.@each')
});
```

How come `notes.length` is `undefined`?

I've simplified this example... I can't use `{{notes.length}}` in my situation as there will be more calculations going on—this is just the first step.

Comment: Not familiar with Ember, but this looks like the everyday async problem, if `this.get` is async, then you can't do that.

Comment: Everything in Ember is async, but I've tried `this.get('notes').then(...) and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what your json looks like? Ember Data doesn't like when your one to many is nested, it wants you to "side load" your data much like the way it would be stored in a database.

Comment: In your accounts controller try `this.get('notes.length')`.

Comment: @BFree I'm just using fixtures at this point and nothing is embedded. For example, the `notes` attribute on an Account model looks like this: `notes: [1,2]`.

Comment: @kiwiupover Thanks! I've used that format before—not sure how it didn't come to mind here. Do you know what's going behind the scenes? Ember must wait for the promise to resolve and then return the length automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You marked `notes` association as async so `this.get('notes')` returns a promise. Promises do not have `length` property hence getting `undefined`.

To get data in an async association call `then` on returned promise with a function as argument. Association data will be passed to that function as first argument.

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  oldNotesCount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.get('notes').then(function(notes){
      _this.set('oldNotesCount', notes.get('length');
    });
    return null;
  }.property('notes.@each')
});
```

Comment: This works but it feels strange. Is using `.set('prop')` inside the definition for said `prop` really the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @EliDupuis Unfortunately to best of my knowledge Ember Object treats a promise as value of a property like any other value so currently this is the only way I know of. However I'm considering creating a pull request against Ember for adding support of waiting for a returned promise in property definition function to resolve then return resolved data of that promise as property value. Please implement this PR if you have the time.